# Conteúdo Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Existe a possibilidade do Wordpress trazer informações do banco sem ser em forma de Posts? Caso eu queira fazer um site "convencional" como eu cadastraria e puxaria essa informação no WP?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor como é isso de "em forma de posts"? E qual tecnologia vai usar no site convencional? Parece que quer cadastrar informações fora do WP, é correto?

Comment: Meu conhecimento em WP seria o basico de if haveposts() bla bla bla rs. Porém o site tem informações, que não seria exibida como posts e sim como informações comuns. Blocos de informações.

Comment: Tudo bem, mas então o que vc quer é puxar as informações do WP dentro de um site PHP, por exemplo? E em relação ao cadastro, qual seu problema com o backend do WP?

Answer (score 1):

Uma função simples para carregar o conteúdo da página no wordpress seria assim:

A função:

```
function get_first_page_content($id){
    $page_id = $id;
    $page_data = get_page($page_id);
    return $page_data->post_content;
}
```

E a chamada dentro da página:

```
<?php echo get_first_page_content($ID_PAGE);?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que percebi, quer saber como usar dados do banco de dados personalizados, ou seja efectuar as suas próprias recolhas de informação das tabelas, ou até de novas tabelas que tenha necessidade.

As informações necessárias de como efectuar as CRUD functions no wordpress encontra-se em:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar suas tabelas personalizadas dentro do banco de dados do Wordpress sem nenhum problema e alimentá-las com formulários e o que desejar, e depois buscar estas informações com a mesma facilidade através de `mysql`, `mysqli` ou `pdo` como desejar.

Adicionalmente, estaria fazendo um clone do `page.php` e renomeando como `page_custom.php` e colocando todos os códigos necessários de `requisições`, `html` e `css` dentro desse arquivo `php` bastando depois ir até a administração do `Wordpress` em Páginas, vai criar uma página e chamá-la do que desejar e então vai procurar modelo da página aonde vai escolher o modelo criado por você mesmo dentro do `page_custom.php` ... exemplo:

```
<?php

      /* Template name: Page Custom */

      Todo o meu código personalizado aqui.

?>
```

Basta depois como disse escolher seu modelo `Page Custom` dentro de ...

```
Páginas > Nome da Minha Página > Dropdown Modelo de Página
```